# Как в Unity+ Vuforia динамически создавать imageTarget

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, vuforia

**Проект делается на android**

Мне нужно, чтобы название кабинетов брались из базы данных. А затем на сцене динамически создавались объекты ImageTarget, названия которых будут такие же, как названия кабинетов. Type должен быть равен From Database, Database = KEP_AR, Image Target = номер кабинета.

```
using Assets.Scripts;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using static UnityEngine.GraphicsBuffer;

public class ARManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    GetTextFromDB DB = new GetTextFromDB();
    [SerializeField] GameObject prefab;

    private async void Awake()
    {
        // Получаем список кабинетов из базы данных.
        List<TimeTable> cabinets = await DB.getCabinets(SessionManager.courposeId);
        var distincatCabintes = new List<TimeTable>();
        // Убираем повторяющиеся кабинеты
        foreach (var cab in cabinets)
        {
            var result = distincatCabintes.FirstOrDefault(e => e.cabinetNumber == cab.cabinetNumber);
            if (result is null)
            {
                distincatCabintes.Add(cab);
            }
        }
        // Создаем кабинеты на основании списка
        foreach (TimeTable t in distincatCabintes)
        {
            GameObject gameObject = Instantiate(prefab);
            gameObject.name = t.cabinetNumber;
            var imageTarget = gameObject.GetComponent<ImageTargetBehaviour>();
            imageTarget.ImageTargetType = ImageTargetType.PREDEFINED;

        }


    }
}
```

Этот код создает объекты ImageTarget, однако я никак не могу сделать назначение им определенного ImageTarget, чтобы они на него реагировали. Они сохраняют тот же, что и в префабе.

Создает объекты ImageTarget
[image: Создает объекты ImageTarget]

Не настраивает им Image Target, а оставляет тот, что был в префабе
[image: Не настраивает им Image Target, а оставляет тот, что был в префабе]

Мне нужно как-то настроить, чтобы динамически создавались и объекты и информация бралась из базы данных, заранее скаченной.
В объекте ImageTargetBehaviour нет параметра DataSet или Database